# Most Standard way to Set Font Sizes in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size

I've been working in HTML/CSS for years, but I'd like to clarify something about setting font sizes. What is the best format to set your font?

Typically, i've been setting  with a font-size in a percentage, and then using em to change it up or down from there.

Is this the most standard way to do it? I've seen fonts declared in pixels, points, with relative keywords like "larger" or "smaller" I've seen it set as percentages, etc.

So what's the most standard? Is the most standard the best? any research to back it up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're all [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props). Use what works for you.

Comment: I appreciate the link to the specs - This is exactly the type of thing I was hoping for when I asked for research to back it up.

Answer (score 27):

What I learnt at school is the following:

Set font-size in body with percent to 62.5%:

```
body {
      font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Then you can use em in the same sense as you would use pixels, except you divide by 10.

For example:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 1.4em; /* 14px */
}
```

We learnt to use em for 'elastic' layouts. If you specify your font-size in em, the text will keep its proportions after a user zooms in or out.

Then again, I see people use px or other declarations for fonts all the time; as far as I know they're all standard. I guess it just comes down to creating the best user-experience.

Comment: Thanks for this. Where is the 62.5% derived from?

Comment: @Dan - It's based on the assumption that the default font size for browsers is 16px. 16 * 62.5% = 10, hence 1.4em maps to 14px. This assumption has not always been true, but probably works tolerably well for modern browsers which tend to use logical pixels rather than physical ones when zooming web pages.

Comment: @Alohci - Thanks for the clarification. So this is determined on a browser by browser basis, and could fluctuate at any point in the future? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: The default size for 'medium' text is 16px in modern browsers. I doubt that would change anytime soon since it seems to be more or less standard nowadays. There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation about it though.
The 62.5% is basically just a way to make working with em's more easy.

Comment: @Dan - For a variety of reasons, the browser manufacturers don't like to be tied down on default CSS values, and as they write the specs this doesn't get set in stone. So it *could* fluctuate, however, they've all converged on using the same setting in this case, and so I think it is unlikely that they will move away because if they did, it would probably break some web pages and they'd lose market share as users avoided it.

Comment: Alright. Thanks guys, I think this helps me make a decision at any rate! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `font-size` in the `body` tag to `100%`.  That way, people who visited your site will see the text at the right size for what they have set in their browser.  For instance, people with low vision may set the text size larger.  If your `font-size` is set to `100%`, they should see it exactly as desired.

After that, you could set the sizes on your `h1`, `h2`, `p`, etc. with `%` or `em`.

Answer (score 2):

I generally set `html` to `10px`, then use `font-size: 100%` on the `body`. You can then use the px/em ratio `14px`/`1.4em` on elements. The only thing I run into is then if I nest base elements, the font gets all funky, and you have to specify `font-size` on all nested elements.

Example: if I have `p, section, article, div{font-size: 1.6em;}`, any time I have `p, section, article, div` nested, the font becomes proportional to the container. So the `1.6em` that was originally `16px` is now `1.6em` of `16px` (not `10px`) or `25.6px`. You'd have to re-scale the text to `0.625em` (or `16px`/`25.6px` = `0.625em`). You will have more control over consistency across browsers, but it may require a bit more effort from you.

Some may be asking, "Why go through all this hassle?" That is a good question. Here is the answer: Responsiveness. That, and I work for a company that needs to be 508 compliant. That includes ultimate control over starting font sizes. I can't rely on assuming that the end user has "medium" or `16pt` font selected, because the law clearly states it must be X or Y for high contrast, etc..

Comment: For the funky nested element problem, use `rem` instead of `em`, which means `root em`(thus pointing to the `html` `font-size`, not the element's parent. More info and fallback for <IE8 (and other olds) at http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem For compatibility table, http://caniuse.com/#search=rem

Answer (score 2):

There is someone telling it isnt a good thing and can break your layout, see it:  http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/